# Telepen format Android scanner SDK

Tags: android, barcode, barcode-scanner

I am searching for a barcode scanner SDK to integrate into my Android application. The main problem is what I need Telepen format to be supported as well, so I can't use ZXING. Could You please advice some libraries to use in my case except Cognex, because they have no convenient license format.